# I want an <a> to be the same size as a text of a <span>

Tags: html, css

I wanted to adjust an "a" tag in a "span" text so that when I touch the text it takes me to the web page, but I get what comes out in the image:

[image: this image]

the "a" tag is too long

Does anyone know how to make the "a" tag the same size as the text?

but the "a" tag has to adapt to any text, it has to be dynamic

Comment: Welcome to SO!  I recommend all new users visit [ask] for tips on how to write a post that best enables the community to help.  To better assist you, you will need to provide your code as a [mcve] that allows us to reproduce the issue.  Remember, without specific context the community cannot provide specific guidance.  Good luck, and happy coding!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```css
a{ 
  background: pink;
  }

span{
    background-color: lightblue;
    padding: .5rem;
    max-width: fit-content;
  }
```

```html
<span>
  <a href="#">Link</a>
</span>
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you wrapped with you a-Tag a block element. If you dont like this behavior put the a tags inner your div or p tag. I dont know what you are using (div, p, etc) because i didnt see your code. but the behavior would be come from this.

**abstract example**

Change this:

```
<a href="">
  <div>link</div>
</a>
```

To this:

```
<div>
  <a href="">link</a>
</duv>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check following.

```css
span, span a{color:#000; text-decoration:none; font-size:20px;}
```

```html
<span><a href="#">page</a></span>
```

Answer (score 0):

just use this style:

```
<a style="width: auto;"> <span> your text </span> </a>
```